# script não carrega e dependências falham

Tags: javascript, script

Por vezes noto que um script não carrega, e o restante dos scripts que de alguma forma usam ele, acabam falhando.

O que fazer para reconhecer quando não carregou e tentar outra alternativa(como carregar de outro lugar), assim evitando que outros scripts que dependam deste não venham a falhar.

Comment: Como você sabe que não carrega? ele da 404? Por quê ele não carrega?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar um gerenciador de módulos como o [AMD/RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) que faz exatamente isso.

Se quiseres garantir que eles carregam na ordem certa, e sem usar AMD/RequireJS, podes criar um carregador teu que espera que cada um deles carregue.

Seria algo assim:

```
var modulos = [
    'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js',
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js'
];

var carregar = (function () {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    function importar(src, callback) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.async = true;
        s.src = src;
        s.addEventListener('load', callback);
        head.appendChild(s);
    }
    return function processador(arr, done) {
        var next = arr.shift();
        if (next) importar(next, function () {
            processador(arr, done);
        });
        else done();
    }
})();

console.log(typeof jQuery); // undefined
carregar(modulos, function(){
    console.log(typeof jQuery); // function
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq15tapn/

A ideia é ter uma função à qual se passa uma array e uma callback para ser corrida quando as bibliotecas externas tiveres carregado todas.

As partes importantes são:

- `s.addEventListener('load', callback);` que detecta quando o script carregou e chama o processador de novo.
- `var next = arr.shift();` onde vai buscar o proximo url/script. Se não houver mais, vai para o `else` e chama a função `done();` que é a callback que lhe foi passada.

Depois de escrever este código [encontrei outra implementação](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/async-script-loader-with-callback/), ligeiramente mais complexa.