# Como saber se um plugin esta ativo

Tags: jquery

Pessoal estou querendo fazer o meu site apenas com um arquivo JS e nele eu gostaria de saber se um determinado *plugin* esta carregado ja que por exemplo o carrocel eu só carrego numa pagina.

Como eu testo se o *plugin* esta carregado para evitar de ficar dando erros no console?

Answer (score 2):

Podes criar uma função recursiva que verifica se certas globais estão defenidas. Caso não estejam, chama-se a sí própria com um tempo de espera.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
function ready(cb) {
    if (typeof window.meuPlugin == 'undefined') return setTimeout(ready.bind(null, cb), 200);
    else cb();
}

ready(function() { // esta callback será corrida quando a global estiver defenida
    alert('Tudo está carregado!');
});
```

```html
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        // para simular o carregamento
        window.meuPlugin = function() {};
    }, 2000)
</script>
```

Comment: Gostei! Dessa forma teria como verificar se o bootstrap e Angular, por exemplo, foram carregados @Sergio?

Comment: @LucasCosta sim, mas para coisas mais avançadas devias ter um _loader_ mais decente que este exemplo :) [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/), por exemplo. Podes dar uma olhada aqui, um problema parecido: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92772/129

Comment: @Sergio não deu certo. Testei com o plugin SimpleAjaxUploader e so fica com undefined. Fiz assim: typeof  window.SimpleUpload == 'undefined' ? console.log('nao carregado') : console.log('carregado'); Tanto faz se eu carregar ou não o plugin. Ex. <script src="{{ asset('vendor/simple-ajax-uploader/SimpleAjaxUploader.js') }}"></script>

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo podes fazer um exemplo no jsFiddle e colocar aqui?

Comment: @Sergio olha vou citar um exemplo simples. Vamos supor que eu tenha esta linha no meu arquivo JS, $("a#single_image").fancyboxPlus(); e digamos que eu não carregue o facyboxPlus antes deste arquivo JS. Se olhar no console do Chrome vai ter um erro de fancyboxPlus não declarado. Ai a minha pergunta como eu testo se o fancyboxPlus esta carregado?

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo testa com `var carregado = !!$.fn.fancyboxPlus;`